# File command database and identifying text files

Tags: file-format, file-command

Please let me know if below two statements are correct or not:

Folder `/usr/share/mime/magic` has a database/table that will give me what are the current possible file formats (outputs that I can get when I type the `file` command and follow it by a file name).

Whenever the `file` command output contains the word "text" it refers to something that you can read with a text viewer, and anything without "text" is some kind of binary.

Comment: That is one usage of file, note that depend on what do you call text files, .doc, .pdf, .epub are containing text. BTW the man page points to `/usr/share/misc/magic` not to `/usr/share/mime/magic`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Folder /usr/share/mime/magic has a database/table that will give me what are the current possible file formats (outputs that I can get when I type "file" command and follow it by a file).

Correct except that `/usr/share/mime/magic` is not the directory that `file` uses: this file is [only used for the MIME type database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159770/how-to-make-the-file-command-use-the-magic-file-generated-by-update-mime-databas).

From `file`'s manpage: "The information identifying these files is read rom the compiled magic file /usr/share/file/misc/magic.mgc, or the files in the directory /usr/share/file/misc/magic if the compiled file does not exist."

And in fact, in my Arch Linux system, that file belongs to the `file` package.

> Whenever "file" command output contains the word "text" it refers to something that you can read with a text viewer, and anything without "text" is some kind of binary.

Looks correct (I tried to find a counterexample but was unable to).

Comment: Where can i see all possible answers that i can get by running "file" command and following it by a filename? I want to know the data format of random files that users will provide and then based upon the data format handle/process each file differently and therefore, would like to know what are the different answers that i could get..

Comment: @user2543622 You can download `file`'s [source code](ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/file-5.19.tar.gz) and within there you will find the sources of the `magic` file.

Answer (score 3):

The location of the `file` database appears to installation/version-dependent.
[The linuxmanpages.com version of `file(1)`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/file.1.php) says:

> #### FILES
>
> `/usr/share/file/magic.mgc`
>
>   Default compiled list of magic numbers
>
> `/usr/share/file/magic`
>
>   Default list of magic numbers
>
> `/usr/share/file/magic.mime.mgc`
>
>   Default compiled list of magic numbers, used to output mime types when the
>   `-i`
>   option is specified.
>
> `/usr/share/file/magic.mime`
>
>   Default list of magic numbers, used to output mime types when the
>   `-i`
>   option is specified.
>
> `/etc/magic`
>
>   Local additions to magic wisdom.

whereas, on Cygwin and Debian, `file(1)` says

> #### FILES
>
> `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc`     Default compiled list of magic.
>     `/usr/share/misc/magic`         Directory containing default magic files.

To further confuse matters, on Debian, `/usr/share/misc/magic`
is a symbolic link to `/usr/share/file/magic`, which is an empty directory,
while, on Cygwin, `/usr/share/file/magic` is a symbolic link to `/usr/share/misc/magic`,
which is a fairly large file (> 600K). 
So I did the obvious experiment:

```
file /usr/share/misc/magic
/usr/share/misc/magic: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with overstriking
```

I looked at it with `vi`, and it looked like ASCII text
(but I didn’t scrutinize all 17000 lines). 
“with overstriking” seems to indicate the presence of backspaces; see

```
echo -e "1 =\b/ 2" | file -
/dev/stdin: ASCII text, with overstriking
```

so I searched `/usr/share/misc/magic` for backspaces, and I found two.